# Error installing latest IBM MobileFirst tooling

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

Attempting to install the latest version of IBM MobileFirst Tooling into Eclipse, and receiving the following error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unable to read repository at
>   http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mfpsupdate/plugins/com.ibm.etools.webedit.xulrunner_1.0.0.v20151012_0901.jar.
>   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected:
>   9976975; received: 18015

This happens in Luna and Mars...

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed the same release version from the Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Mars. I suspect this is a network-level issue.

Best course of action is to try again later.

Comment: I really think it's a problem with one of the files in the distribution - specifically "com.ibm.etools.webedit.xulrunner_1.0.0.v20151012_0901.jar".

If you look at the artifacts.xml file, it's supposed to be upwards of 10MB.  

<artifact classifier="osgi.bundle" id="com.ibm.etools.webedit.xulrunner" version="1.0.0.v20151012_0901"><properties size="3"><property name="artifact.size" value="9976975"/><property name="download.size" value="9976975"/><property name="download.md5" value="f4e02e86b79eacabdf524c07633dd75c"/></properties></artifact>

But it's only 20K in the distribution...